# Calling a lua function from table.subtable in C++

Tags: c++, function, lua, lua-table

im trying to call a lua function from C++ where function is in subtable of global table. Im using lua version 5.2.* compiled from source.

**Lua function**

```
function globaltable.subtable.hello()
 -- do stuff here
end
```

**C++ code**

```
lua_getglobal(L, "globaltable");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "subtable");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "hello");
if(!lua_isfunction(L,-1)) return;
    lua_pushnumber(L, x);
    lua_pushnumber(L, y);
    lua_call(L, 2, 0);
```

However im unable to call it, i always get an error

> PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to index a nil value)

On line #3: **lua_getfield(L, -1, "hello");**

***What am I missing?***

Side question: I would love to know also how to call function deeper than this - like **globaltable.subtable.subsubtable.hello()** etc.

Thank you!

---

This is what im using to create the globaltable:

```
int lib_id;
lua_createtable(L, 0, 0);
lib_id = lua_gettop(L);
luaL_newmetatable(L, "globaltable");
lua_setmetatable(L, lib_id);
lua_setglobal(L, "globaltable");
```

how do i create the globaltable.subtable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`function` is a keyword in Lua, I am guessing on how did you manage to compile the code:

```
-- test.lua
globaltable = { subtable = {} }
function globaltable.subtable.function()
end
```

When this is run:

```
$ lua test.lua
lua: test.lua:2: '<name>' expected near 'function'
```

Maybe you changed the identifiers for this online presentation, but check that on line 2  `"subtable"` really exists in the `globaltable`, because on line 3, the top of stack is already `nil`.

**Update:**

To create multiple levels of tables, you can use this approach:

```
lua_createtable(L,0,0); // the globaltable
lua_createtable(L,0,0); // the subtable
lua_pushcfunction(L, somefunction);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "somefunction"); // set subtable.somefunction
lua_setfield(L, -2, "subtable");     // set globaltable.subtable
```

Comment: function globaltable.subtable.function() was supposed to be just for orientation - lets assume its "function globaltable.subtable.hello()"

Comment: Then my second point applies. It looks like `subtable` cannot be found in `globaltable`. Try creating a Lua [stackDump](http://www.lua.org/pil/24.2.3.html) function to show the content of the stack, and call it after every Lua operation.

Comment: Ive edited the question above - im creating this globaltable in C++ and i don't know how to create the subtable in globaltable

Answer (score 0):

```
lua_newtable(L);
luaL_newmetatable(L, "globaltable");
lua_newtable(L); //Create table
lua_setfield(L, -2, "subtable"); //Set table as field of "globaltable"
lua_setglobal(L, "globaltable");
```

This is what i was looking for.